# Azure Gateway Ingress Controller

Tags: microservices, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I am using the Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller with AKS, it quite okay to me with url routing, TLS, web application firewall. But it looks like the AGIC doesn't support Authentication (I'd just need to have basic authentication)

Is there a way to have the Authentication features enabled (just with Azure stuff)? Or I have to implement the Authentication at api level (every single micro service)?

In fact, I might need a gateway that I can offload more functionalities like authentication, logging, monitoring

Regards

Comment: As of 2021.06.23, [Azure Application Gateway does not support Authentication](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/860) (APIM does -> here is a workaround with [AGIC + APIM](https://medium.com/@jw_ng/using-azure-application-gateway-with-api-management-service-f9b9b2cd1731))

Comment: Very important (and needed) feature and still no progress (frustrating) -> https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/19473664-authentication-support-for-application-gateway

Comment: Submit feedback here to get this feature: https://aka.ms/ApplicationGatewayCohort

Comment: Updated feedback link: 
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/74b99764-8526-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789